# html table column size

Tags: html, css, html-table, size

I was wondering if there was a way to resize a table the way I want?
I'd like to have a table with X columns of which only one column can have a variable size, the others have to adapt to their size, while maintaining a minimum width.
EX.

```
| Col0 | Col1 | Col 2          | Col3     | Col4              | Col5 |
| dat1 | d    | dat3dater      | datadata | datatdatadatadata |  dat |
|      | dat2 | asdasd         | datad    | datadatadatad.....|      |
```

In this case Col 2 uses the remaining space and the others col adapts to their contents.

What is the simplest way to stylize this ?

Comment: I would try stacktable.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like responsive design.So you can either use a framework or simple use my example and twist it as you like.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

th, td {
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Responsive Table</h2>
<p>Sample data take from w3schools.com .</p>

<div style="overflow-x:auto;">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>LONG ONE</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>This wİll be longer so you can see the difference i hope</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works as expected. Can you explain to me why it does work this way? I don't see any rules that explicitly declare that the LONG ONE column have to use the space that is left, while other columns have to adapt. Sorry again people